# Do not interrupt script if command fails, but collect exit code

Tags: linux, bash

I need to execute a command in a script with `set -e` set. This command is an exception to the general script flow, in that it could fail and that would not be critical: the script can continue. I want that command to **not** interrupt the script; instead I want to keep the exit code for later evaluation.

I have come up with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
false && res1=$? || res1=$?
true  && res2=$? || res2=$?
echo $res1
echo $res2
```

(My command would be in place of `false` or `true`)

Is this the right approach?

### EDIT

Incidentally, this very similar construct does not work at all:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
false || res1=$? && res1=$?
true  || res2=$? && res2=$?
echo $res1
echo $res2
```

### EDIT

Testing one of the suggestions:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
false || { res1=$?; true; }
true  || { res2=$?; true; }
echo $res1
echo $res2
```

This does not work. Result is:

```
1
(empty line)
```

Comment: @Jahid: no, because a failing command will interrupt script, which is what I want to avoid

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that...

Comment: @Jahid: Maybe `false ; res1=$?` would be better? Would that record the result of the previous command, without interrupting script?

Comment: It would interrupt the script

Comment: false || { res1=$?; true; } Does that work ?

Comment: @MayurNagekar: I want to collect result in both failing and success cases

Comment: it should work in both the cases. did you try ?

Comment: false || { res1=$?; true; }

true && { echo $?;  }

Comment: @jahid see my comment above. It works for me.

Comment: @MayurNagekar: it does not work when the command is successful, only when it fails. See my edit

Comment: I just created a file test.sh and it works for me as you can see in the below answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to use `&&` and `||` to form a ternary expression; it's too fragile. Just use an `if` statement.

```
if cmd; then res=$?; else res=$?; fi
```

Better(?) yet, you can put the assignment in the condition itself, reducing repetition at the cost of having a seemingly vacuous `if` statement:

```
if cmd; res=$?; then :; fi
```

That might be more clearly written with a single `||` though:

```
{ cmd; res=$?; } || true
```

(Notice I've used `true` and `:` interchangeably; `:` is guaranteed by POSIX to be a shell built-in, but `true` is probably more readable.)

Comment: There you are talking!

Comment: @Jahid Thanks; no idea why I typed `$!` originally.

Comment: This kind of thing sometimes happens :D. When I upvoted your answer, there were three `$!`, yet I didn't notice that. Even after **three** upvotes, no-one noticed... :D

Answer (score 1):

Putting the `&&` after `||` doesn't have the effect that you want. For example,

```
false || echo true && echo false
```

will print both true and false, i.e whatever after `&&` will be executed whether the first command was successful or not. You can do it like this:

```
command && res1=$? || res1=$?
```

In this case, if `command` succeeds, the third one doesn't get executed, if fails, the second one doesn't get executed.

EDIT

As [chepnar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40547813/3744681) mentioned, the use of `&&` and `||` isn't full-proof. The behavior isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Ok, so my original implementation is the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than capturing same exit code twice why not just turn off `-e`, capture the exit status and turn on `-e` again like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

set +e          # turn off exit on error
false; res1=$?  # run command1 and capture exit status1
true; res2=$?   # run command2 and capture exit status2
set -e          # turn on exit on error

echo $res1
echo $res2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid having set +e / set -e all around my code.

Comment: Hmm ok , but it will be cleaner than capturing same `$?` twice.

Comment: Solution by @chepner is very clean.

Comment: Yes, totally agree with that.